# Prevention triggers

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, insert, date-arithmetic

I have a table like this:

```
StudentID  Student Name   Birthdate Student Birthplace Gender Height Weight 
--------- --------------- --------- ------------------ ------ ------ ------ 
83        Adam Stone      30-JUN-94 Towson, USA        M      193    88               
84        Stephanie Love  17-JUN-93 KL,Malaysia        F      176    67                 
85        Rachel Kim      17-FEB-92 Seoul, South Korea F      179    56
```

How do i write a trigger to prevent any student under the age of 15 from being stored in the student's table?

Comment: Do you already have a trigger definition that is giving some problems?

Comment: It's not a very useful naming convention to repeat the table's name in every column.

Comment: Please don't bother changing the table names and other details unless they are really germane to the question.  You're just wasting people's energies.

Answer (score 4):

You have a Date of Birth.  So you need to determine that the DoB is at least sixteen years before today.  There are various different ways of doing this; here's one using an [interval literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#i38598).

```
create or replace trigger students_biur
     before insert or update on students for each row 
begin
    if (:new.student_birthdate + INTERVAL '15' YEAR ) < sysdate
    then 
         raise_application_error( -20000, 'This student is too young be registered.');     
    end if;
end;
```

This trigger also checks for updates, to prevent subsequent changes invalidating an student.

---

The trigger name `students_biur` is just a convention I use: the table name with a suffix indicating *B*efore *I*nsert *U*pdate for each *R*ow.

RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR is a standard procedure for throwing user-defined exceptions with a message.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS99960).

Oracle reserves the range -20999 to -20000 for user-defined errors; any other number may clash with a oracle-defined exception.

Comment: You probably meant [interval literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#i38598)

Comment: oh my thank you so much. athletes_biur is just the name of the trigger is it may i ask? what does -20000 from the raise_application_error mean?

Comment: @VincentMalgrat - you're right: I adapted some existing code without testing it.  My bad.

Comment: +1 - I would note, however, that this has the potential to generate errors for those folks born on February 29.  Adding an interval of 15 years to February 29, 2012, for example, generates an error that the date isn't valid (ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified) since February 29, 2027 isn't valid.  I would tend to use `add_months(:new.student_birthdate, 12*15)` instead since it won't generate errors. I think you also have your inequality condition reversed-- I think you want `< sysdate` not `> sysdate`.

Comment: @JustinCave - I'm sure I had the condition correct, but the code has been edited so many times. As for the use of INTERVAL, the question was originally phrased as checking for people under *16* years; in that case my solution would have been safe until it started checking somebody with a DoB of 29-FEB-2084 :)

Comment: Well, you don't want to be responsible for creating a Y2.1K scare, do you?